# Bootstrap autocomplete dropdown does not filter search

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, autocomplete

I can't figure out how to use Bootstrap's autocomplete dropdown to filter the results as I am typing in the search box. Currently, when I type a word, all of the options possible will appear in the dropdown and matching partial strings will be bolded. Is there a way to make it so that only the options with partial matches appear in the dropdown as I continue typing? This is my current code for reference:

```
<select class="form-control basicAutoSelect" name="simple_select"
            placeholder="type to search..."
            data-url="test-list.json" autocomplete="off"></select>

<script>
    $('.basicAutoSelect').autoComplete();
</script>
```

Comment: It's better to leave filtering in backend / server side rather than sending all result then filtering it in client side with javascript

Answer (score 0):

The filtering is up to you. You can do it server sided (I strongly recommend it) or static (it's 'OK' for small items). Whatever option you use, you should use [events.search](https://bootstrap-autocomplete.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#search) callback. As every use case is different, this component implements only the basic pattern of calling an url passing a qry parameter and showing results.